# Implementing custom scrollbar WINAPI

Tags: user-interface, winapi, window, scrollbar, clip

I'm designing a GUI framework.
To minimize window-to-window intenal OS messaging, I'm implementing a LAYOUT class
that is just a logical rectangle that manages WINDOWS and other LAYOUTS in some way.

Here is the structure

```
class UIElement; //base class for all the stuff
class SimpleWindow:publioc UIElement; //WINAPI window that has HWND

class Layout:public UIElement{
public:
std::vector<UIElement> elements_list;
virtual void ManageElements()=0;
}
class ColumnLayout:public Layout{
void ManageElements()override;
...
```

On the jpeg below you can see a visualization of the general idea.
The LAYOUT class has the "logical" ownership of all the child elements. But in terms of windows api the actual (hwnd) parent of all the windows in a layout - is the PARENT WINDOW.

[image]

This layout system works fine on resizing and fitting one layout to another and to parent windos but I'm stuck at implementing scrollbar functionality. My idea is that I should create a derived class say 
`class LayoutScrollable:public Layout`
and create a custom scrollbar window contol (that is easy to do) on the right side of it and position the rest of the layout complex content on the left side, channel the change of the scrollbar status to child windows positions and CLIP AWAY everything that's outside the layout;

My first attempt was to do this clipping in WM_NCPAINT callback. But although clipped out area becomes hidden, it still gets all the mouse messages and blocks the mouse to fall through to the underlying windows.

Maybe I should respond to WM_NCCALCSIZE , well I'll try it now. But maybe anyone knows other nice ways?

Comment: The easiest way to clip child windows is to put them inside another window. Then you just scroll them out of view.

Comment: Yes and I've written that I dont want to mess around with more windows that I actually need